# why object key is not deleted from object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object in my demo  .

```
var vm = {
    a: {
        module: "not test"
    },
    b: {
        module: "test"
    }
}
```

I need to delete the key of object which have `"test"` module name.

Expected output

```
vm = {
    a: {
        module: "not test"
    }
}
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kymdsj1s/

Here is my code. I used the `delete` keyword but it does not work for me.

```
var tempModule = "test";
var vm = {
    a: {
        module: "not test"
    },
    b: {
        module: "test"
    }
}

deleteItem(tempModule)

function deleteItem(moduleName) {
    if (Object.key(vm) == moduleName)
        delete vm
}

console.log(vm)
```

Comment: Note, `Object.key()` should be `Object.keys()` ; also `Object.keys()` returns an array , which can be accessed using bracket notation; e.g., `Object.keys(vm).forEach(function(key) {if (vm[key] === moduleName) delete vm[key]})` ; or `Object.keys(vm)[0]//a` , `Object.keys(vm)[1]//b`

Comment: For starters check console for errors . It is `Object.keys()` with an `s` and that returns an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `delete vm` which will not delete what you expect - `vm` is your entire view model object and if you want to delete the `b` property of it here's what you may try:

```
var tempModule = 'test';
var vm = {
    a: { module: 'not test' },
    b: { module: 'test' }
};

function deleteItem(moduleName) {
    for (var key in vm) {
        if (vm.hasOwnProperty(key) && vm[key]['module'] === moduleName) {
            delete vm[key];
        }
    }
}

deleteItem(tempModule);
console.log(vm);
```

And here's the [`updated fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/kymdsj1s/3/).

Answer (score 1):

Note, `Object.key()` should be `Object.keys()` ; also `Object.keys()` returns an array , which can be accessed using bracket notation; e.g.,

```
Object.keys(vm)[0] // "a"

Object.keys(vm)[1] // "b"
```

---

```
function deleteItem(moduleName) {
  Object.keys(vm).forEach(function(key) {
    if (vm[key]["module"] === moduleName) delete vm[key]
  })
}
```

```js
var tempModule = "test";
var vm = {
  a: {
    module: "not test"
  },
  b: {
    module: "test"
  }
}

console.log(Object.keys(vm)[0], Object.keys(vm)[1]);

deleteItem(tempModule);

function deleteItem(moduleName) {
  Object.keys(vm).forEach(function(key) {
    if (vm[key]["module"] === moduleName) delete vm[key]
  })
}

console.log(vm)
```